# Adding UITableView with autolayouts programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

When I add UITableView programmatically and use Autolayouts, I usually write code like this:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
                                                           style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
self.tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
NSDictionary *views = @{@"tableView": self.tableView};
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[tableView]|"
                                                                 options:0
                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                   views:views]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[tableView|"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
```

The default initialiser for UITableView requires some CGRect to be positioned in, but when we use AutoLayout, there is no need to set frame programmatically.

- Do I add the UITableView correctly?
- Is there a way to avoid "dummy" CGRect?

Comment: I am attempting the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: I don't think this has any affect.